# ISV: add process to managed package for GE/PE

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, isv

Is it possible to add processes to a managed package (passed sec-review, aloha-app) and still install it to Group/Professional Editions?

I know, that the feature [is only available at EE/PXE/UE](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm), but maybe SF is going the same route as for APEX code. I did not find a definitive answer at the documentation. Maybe someone here does have some experience to share.